# Возможно ли программно определять IP адрес в C#?

Tags: c#, ip, cmd

Возможно ли определить свой IP через программу на C# ? Желательно локальный IP и внешний. И, если возможно узнавать, через роутер, то как ? Можете подсказать в каком направлении копать или пример кода продемонстрировать мне ?

Comment: А что есть "внешний" адрес? (Кстати, из букваря. IP адрес не принадлежит хосту, но только (суб-)интерфейсам)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Возможно:

```
foreach (System.Net.IPAddress ip in System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ip.ToString());
        }
```

Это локальные адреса

Comment: Благодарю )

Answer (score 6):

Внешний IP никто кроме роутера не знает, поэтому единственный способ его узнать, спросить у кого-то за роутером свой IP, например тут http://www.myip.ru/ru-RU/index.php